# find transformation matrix by knowing the distances only

Tags: math, linear-algebra, transformation, point-clouds

Assume we have a point cloud A of size 4xN including some points A1,...,An in 3D space. each point is a 4x1 vector (x,y,z,1). this point cloud is **fully known**. we have the points' position in space.

Then, someone applies an arbitrary 4x4 **rigid** transformation matrix **T** to the point cloud. so the result would be a new point cloud B = TA. obviously, each point in B have a correspondence in A. so for example, B1 corresponds to A1, and Bn corresponds to An.

Now the problem is that we need to obtain the transformation matrix. But the only information we have is the **euclidian distance** between A and B. in particular, we have N distances A1B1, A2B2, ..., AnBn.

How can we obtain the transformation matrix T by only knowing the euclidian distance between the corresponding points?

take a look at the following figure as an illustration:
[image]

Comment: You want to solve the system of n equations `||T Ai - Ai|| = di`, where the unknown are the 12 variables that compose matrix T (matrix T is 4x4, but its fourth row is 0 0 0 1).

Comment: If T was a translation, that is there is a vector v so that B[j] = A[j]+v for all j, then d(A[j],B[j]) = length(v). So you can't recover v from the distances, only it's length

Comment: @dmuir I agree, there might be non-unique solutions to this problem. But anyway, I'm wondering if I can somehow obtain all possible solutions!